# nextjs - meta title and description not working when share link on social media

Tags: reactjs, next.js, meta-tags

### Title and description are set like here but I'm pulling from api.

[image]

### This is what the title and description look like when I share the link on Discord or any other social media

site: https://istanbulfood.be/

---

[image]

**next-seo codes I use:**

```
<NextSeo
  title={title}
  description={description}
  canonical={`${siteSettings.author.websiteUrl}${path}`}
  openGraph={{
    url: `${siteSettings.author.websiteUrl}/${path}`,
    title,
    description,
    images: [
      {
        url: '/assets/images/logo.png',
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        alt: 'İstanbulfood',
      },
      {
        url: '/assets/images/logo.png',
        width: 900,
        height: 800,
        alt: 'İstanbulfood',
      },
    ],
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I solved it yesterday, got the same problem in Whatsapp link preview. Don't know if you solved it already, but the key is to put the info outside of components that would run javascript before rendering them, like in `_app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [open graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) in your site markup to get rich link support in social media.

---

Inside `openGraph` props, can you try to add another attribute `type: 'website'`? Also use `full url` for your `images` inside openGraph. Please visit [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istanbulfood.be) to test your rich link

Comment: i added the codes i used

Comment: Inside `openGraph` props, can you try to add another attribute `type: 'website',` ? Also use `full url` for your images inside `openGraph`. Please visit [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istanbulfood.be) to test your rich link